# How to add a JLabel to a JPanel in a different class and keep its set attributes.

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jpanel, jlabel

I'm creating a card game in Java. I have a JPanel (actually a JLayeredPane) in my GUI class and JLabels containing the card images are added to it as they are dealt. These JLabels are generated in my Card class and called using a getImage() method. This method returns a JLabel like so:

```
public JLabel getImage(){

 String theCardName = getName()+getSuit();

 theCardName = theCardName.replaceAll("\\s+","");

 image = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("Images\\"+theCardName+".png"));

 cardImage = new JLabel(image,JLabel.CENTER);

 return cardImage;
}
```

In my Gui class, I add the card to a JlayeredPane like this:

```
Card card = new Card();
jLayeredPane1.add(card.getImage(),new Integer(i));
i++ //this is just so each card is layered on top of the proceeding card.
```

Except I need to set the bounds for the label and would like to do that in the getImage() method. So I add this line to the getImage() method:

```
cardImage.setBounds(5, 5, 60, 100); //(The first parameter in that method actually gets incremented every time the methods is called so the cards get spread out, but that's irrelevant)
```

This does not work. These bound parameters do not seem to come with the label when it is returned to my Gui class.

What I had to do was this in the Gui class instead:

```
Card card = new Card();
JLabel label = card.getImage();
label.setBounds(5, 5, 60, 100);
jLayeredPane1.add(label,new Integer(i));
i++;
```

But I would prefer to set the bounds in the getImage() method for a number of reasons I won't go into. Why am I not able to  or is there a way?

Comment: There is no reason you can't use the setBounds() method in your getImage() method. Post your [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: How do you post a SSCE? Just post all the code for the Gui, and Card class and link to one image, people could download?

Comment: You post the code the same way you posted the above code,. All the code should be in a single class and should demonstrate the problem, not your entire application. Then we can copy/paste/compile/execute the code to see if we get the same behaviour.